# Getting Tooltip of a control without Tooltip instance

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I would like to get the tooltip text associated with a control(Ex: button) without `Tooltip` instance.

i have tried this: [with the help of tooltip instance]

```
  private void btnGetToolTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String toolTipOfSubmit = toolTip1.GetToolTip(btnSubmit);
        MessageBox.Show(toolTipOfSubmit);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

it's working but i don't want to take the help of Tootip instace (here : toolTip1) to get the tooltip text.

is it possible? please help me.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. You may have two different ToolTip instances, each one with different text associated with the control. Why do you need this functionality? What is is trying to solve?